# Delphi DCrypt - How to isolate SHA256?

Tags: delphi, hash, components, vcl, sha

I'm writing my own component in Delphi XE2 but I primary use C++ Builder. That is why I need some help regarding Delphi DCrypt library.

My new component needs to have a method (function) that calculates sha256 hash value of a string. I know for DCrypt library and I use it for some time but this time I need to isolate SHA256 hash algorithm and add it in my new component.

DCrypt has stored SHA256 in DCPsha256.pas but since I'm not so skilled in Delphi I don't know what to do. I don't need to install TDCP_sha256, I just need to be able to calculate SHA256 inside my new component.

Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the objects manually.  Use the existing units and do not modify DCPCrypt.

How to create an object:

```
var
  x:TDCP_sha256;

begin
  x := TDCP_sha256.Create(nil);
  try 
     // do stuff, create hash, whatever.
  finally
    x.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You do not need to install any packages in order to provide access to the classes that you want to use, unless you wanted to drop them onto a form or data module. If you write code like the above code, you don't need to modify anything.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

1. one: do not do. It better to distribute DCrypt library with ur component and allow user to update it to more recent versions.
   If sha256 would turn buggy, or incompatible with newer Delphi version - what would you do ? If u use DCrypt, then you just download new version of it. If you isolated it - then u have to fix it yourself. Do you have enough skils in both Delphi and crypto mathematics, to always doo all fixes of sha256 code and new Delphi versions in future ?
2. But if you insist - then launch to Delphi side by side. In one open DCrypt sources, in another open new empty unit. Copy sha256-generating procedure from DCrypt to empty unit and try to compile. Delphi would tell you of unknown identificators. Look into Dcrypt Delphi and find the declarations of them. If they are from DCpypt too - then copy them again into the new unit. If they are from RTL/VCL - add the unit into USES of your new unit. And try to compile again. Repeat this until all the identifiers are either resolved by USES or copied from DCrypt into your file.
   After it compiles - take some file and calculate hashes by DCrypt and by you new library - if they are different, that means you had borken something and have to find and fix it (you have enought crypto math experience, don't you).

I made Win64 asm optimizations for Spring4D sha code and all that code was covered by unit tests, so i always new if my optimizations broke things or not. Without those total testign policy i'd not be able to do it.

I strongly advice you to stick with DCrypt or Lockbox3 or Spring4D or any other strong living library and not isolate yourself. Keep together with community and you can use their labor for yourself. Isolate - and you would have to re-do it each time new bug or incompatibility would face up.

You cannot extract code from library - why do you think you would be able to upgrade that code to XE4/5/6... and prove it was not broken ?

Comment: It seams to me very complicated to force users (programmers) to install the entire DCrypt just for one my component. I would rather avoid it to simplify things. But if there is no choice.....

Comment: there is always choice. Go to Torry.net or to Google and find ANY sha256 implementation you'd like. But after that - be maintainer of that hash implementation. Do you want it, can you? btw, using libraries would also allow you to switch hashing as you like just by changing hash class. I don;t know what is DCypt for Delphi and if it is complex or not, but maybe another library would suffice.

Comment: You may also do it one more way - design some simplistic hashing interface. Then add DCrypt-based implementation, add LockBox3-based implementation, etc. If i was a user of your component, i'd probably not mind adding 1st crypto lib, but i'd definitely be irritated by adding one MORE lib. So decoupling hash implementation from your component would provide users to either use your default engine (which you'd easily switch if you'd like another lib in future) or use the library they already have. Just use DUnit to test that implementation is correct, not leaking, etc